# Unavailable to install Systemfonts packages in Bioconductor 3.12 (R 4.0.1)

Tags: r, bioconductor

I recently upgraded R to 4.0.1. When i install a package for bioconductor, Systemfonts, the installation failed, and an information stated that it is because one package is not found

```
freetype2 was not found in the pkg-config search path. 
perhaps you should add the directory containing `freetype2.pc' to the pkg_config_path environment 
variable no package 'freetype2' found
```

when i try to install freetype2, it shows that freetype2 is not available to R 4.0.1.

any one know what should i do?

Comment: How did you try to install freetype2? This is not an R package, but has to be installed through e.g. [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/freetype) on macOS. That said it would also help if you specify what OS you are on.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on macOS, install freetype with [Homebrew](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/freetype), from a terminal:

```
brew install freetype
```

Then re-start R and try installing *systemfonts* again from source:

```r
install.packages("systemfonts", type = "source")
```

Comment: i manage to solve the problem before your answer. During installation of a package, i was ask if i want to download sources the package which needs compilation, after I choose no instead of yes, the installation went smoothly. I don't know why. But thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: @pill45 yes that might also work, but generally when you don’t install from source, you’re not using the most recent stable version of a package, which might cause other problems later on. However, if it’s working for you then just stick with it :)

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve the problem before @milanmlft answer. During installation of a package, i was ask

```
do you want to install from sources the package which needs compilation?
```

After I choose no, instead of yes initially, the installation went smoothly. I think this may be a way to solve the problem although I don't know the exact reason. But thank you @milanmlft answer and help.