# fatal error installing systemfonts in jupyter R docker

Tags: r, jupyter-lab, jupyter-irkernel

I am running jupyterlabs on docker and wanted to install the `rvg` package. One of the dependencies are `systemfonts`, and when I tried to install this using `install.packages("systemfonts")` I get:

```
Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.yu.ac.kr/src/contrib:
  cannot open URL 'https://cran.yu.ac.kr/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
Warning message:
package ‘systemfonts’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

So I downloaded the `tar.gz` file from CRAN and installed from file, but I get a fatal error:

```
    > install.packages("systemfonts_1.0.2.tar.gz", repo = NULL, type = "source")
* installing *source* package ‘systemfonts’ ...
** package ‘systemfonts’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lfontconfig -lfreetype
** libs
rm -f systemfonts.so caches.o cpp11.o dev_metrics.o font_matching.o font_registry.o ft_cache.o string_shape.o font_metrics.o font_fallback.o string_metrics.o emoji.o cache_store.o init.o unix/FontManagerLinux.o
x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++ -std=gnu++11 -I"/opt/conda/lib/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/opt/conda/lib/R/library/cpp11/include' -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /opt/conda/include -I/opt/conda/include -Wl,-rpath-link,/opt/conda/lib   -fpic  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden  -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /opt/conda/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/conda/feedstock_root/build_artifacts/r-base-split_1607284869564/work=/usr/local/src/conda/r-base-4.0.3 -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/conda=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix  -c caches.cpp -o caches.o
In file included from caches.h:7,
                 from caches.cpp:1:
ft_cache.h:9:10: fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory
    9 | #include <ft2build.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/opt/conda/lib/R/etc/Makeconf:181: caches.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘systemfonts’
* removing ‘/opt/conda/lib/R/library/systemfonts’
Warning message:
In install.packages("work/corehead_data/systemfonts_1.0.2.tar.gz",  :
  installation of package ‘work/corehead_data/systemfonts_1.0.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

I tried to follow this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62372181/unavailable-to-install-systemfonts-packages-in-bioconductor-3-12-r-4-0-1), by typing in `sudo apt-get install -y libfreetype6` to get `freetype`, but it is already the newest version. I'm not sure what else to try, hopefully someone can provide some expertise. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for "`ft2build.h: No such file or directory` Ubuntu" leads to [this issue on systemfonts library GitHub](https://github.com/r-lib/systemfonts/issues/50) where a workaround for the compilation error for Ubuntu 20.04 is shown:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libfontconfig1-dev
```

This should help you to compile library from the `tar.gz` source.

Comment: hi @krassowski, I tried that but got this message: `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Unable to locate package libfontconfig1-dev`; then I tried without `-dev`: `Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
libfontconfig1 is already the newest version (2.13.1-2ubuntu3). libfontconfig1 set to manually installed. 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

Comment: that github post mentioned re-installing `freetype` thru Brew, i tried to install free type but it is already newest version as well.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I mean I am confused because you say that you used `sudo apt-get` which looks very much like you are using Ubuntu but the you mention Brew which sounds like Mac, so I am not sure what exactly is in your docker image (nor what version of R are you using).

Comment: yeah the docker image is based off of Ubuntu, `VERSION="20.04.1 LTS (Focal Fossa)`. The SO post you referenced mentioned use of `Brew` to install `freetype`. I was just pointing out that fact from the post.

Comment: If you are using Ubuntu 20.04 then this package is available: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/focal/+package/libfontconfig1-dev. Maybe you need to run `sudo apt update` first? Sorry, but at this point this issue is no longer related to JupyterLab, IRkernel or even R, it is just an Ubuntu configuration issue and this is outside of my expertise.

Comment: your suggestion to update worked. I was then able to install `libfontconfig1-dev`. Thank you very much!